# emacs python navigate start or end of for loop

Tags: python, emacs

In emacs when editing in python language, how do I navigate the cursor from the beginning of a for loop to the end of it?

In other languages that use curly brackets, typing `C-M-n` or `C-M-p` from the curly-braket position moves the cursor to the end or the beginning of a loop. Is there a similar key combo for python code?

Example: navigate from beginning of foo loop to end, or bar or xyz loops:

```
for foo in foolist:
    for bar in barlist:
        if foo > 100:
            print "foo large"
        else:
            if bar > 100:
                print "bar large"
            else:
                print "bar small"
    for xyz in xyzlist:
        print "xyz" . xyz
```

EDITED:

I tried with this code below, and beginning to end works, but end to beginning does not work, it jumps from the end of an `else` to the end of the corresponding `if`:

```
(define-key python-mode-map "\C-\M-n" 'python-nav-end-of-block)
(define-key python-mode-map "\C-\M-p" 'python-nav-beginning-of-block)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
python-nav-beginning-of-block
python-nav-end-of-block
```

You can redefine the binding using:

```
(define-key python-mode-map ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp`. It is bound to `C-M-f` and `C-M-b`.

If you like [evil-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil), you can use evil-matchit-mode that extends the use of `%` to sexps (`if`, `for` etc).

Answer (score 0):

With current trunk of python-mode.el

```
py-beginning-of-top-level
```

resp.

```
py-end-of-top-level
```

As you remarked, beginning-of-block would stop also at "if".

BTW a beginning-of-NAME should be delivered for all known loops